# Creating jar executable w/ external jar (JXL) in ECLIPSE java

Tags: eclipse, jar, executable, jxl

I can't find a working solution for my jar executable. The program runs perfect in my Eclipse IDE, but when I attempt to follow Eclipse instructions, the executable does not work with external JAR.

The JXL jar is in my build path. Anyone know how to get this working through Eclipse? I do not have access to command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.) Right-click on project, select pop-up menu entry "Export...".**

[image: Pop-up menu -> Export]

**2.) Select "Java -> Runnable JAR file".**

[image]

**3.) Choose a working launch configuration for running your program via `java -jar MyExecutable.jar` from the command line later. Select an output folder and file name. Select "Package required libraries into generated JAR".**

[image]